# Screaming Frog removes custom request headers

Tags: seo

I need your help.

We are working on Angular SPA that uses token-based authentification (our client app gets token from server and saves it to localstorage). Then in each request to our API client adds special custom header with that token. Out server app authenificates user by that token and sends requested data.

The problem is that Screaming Frog, when executing JavaScript code of out client app, does not sends our custom headers in AJAX requests. And even more, it does not sends `Referrer` header as browser do.

Who worked with Screaming Frog, please help.

Comment: Well, why don't you ask the Screaming Frog support for help? Seems like you pay for it, so let them fix it. I also do not think that you can refactor the applications code anyway.

Comment: @sboesch, Okey, I will write to support. Do you know, Screaming Frog strips custom headers or it sends any request like it would be opened in new tab of the browser?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO, not programming. SEO questions may be asked on [Webmasters.SE](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: My problem is solved. So this question is closed. Sorry for offtopic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed in new version of Screaming Frog

Windows:
https://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/products/seo-spider/beta/ScreamingFrogSEOSpider-7.3-beta-6.exe
Mac:
https://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/products/seo-spider/beta/ScreamingFrogSEOSpider-7.3-beta-6.dmg